# Eclipse + JBoss Tools -> Choose text bundle to be used by default

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I'm using Eclipse (Indigo) and JBoss Tools to edit `.xhtml` files. (As part of a JSF 2 project)

I have a few text bundles and I want one of them to be the default (So when I select text and externalize it, it will check if it exists in the default text bundle that I choose and offer to add it there)

Right now I have some esoteric text bundle chosen automatically (probably by alphabet order) and have to switch manually every time. Annoying!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered...

I've had to change the names of the resources so that the one I wanted to use by default would be the first in alphabetical order.

Ridiculous, I know, but I couldn't find any other way.